# Performance penalty for use of iMessageFilter

Tags: .net, performance, imessagefilter

I would like to implement the `iMessageFilter` in my .Net Winforms application to check for certain messages (you know, WM_[messages]).
I have searched but I could not find any information concerning the performance penalty when using this filter.
Does anyone have experience with the implementation of `iMessageFilter` and the effect on application performance?

I know it also depends on what I will do in the `PreFilterMessage` function. It will compare the `Message.Msg` to specific WM_[messages] or a range of them, up to 20 or so.

Posts that will get my 'answer' mark will probably contain:

- Your experience with iMessageFilter (with absolute performance data?).
- And/Or a description of a method of how I can monitor/determine the penalty on performance by using the iMessageFilter. (Using PerformanceCounter in combination with CPU ticks or so?). The result would be best if it was a relative percentage of CPU usage on the application.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: IMessageFilter only exposes posted messages, user input mostly.  Shoots a hole in your "range" idea.  Perf is never an issue, this is human time, you can burn a million cpu cycles and never notice it.  The obvious thing to do is just try it.

Comment: @HansPassant Just trying it might seem obvious. But it does not necessarily gives a good understanding of the impact on much bigger applications than the one tested on.